# Create spring managed beans with factory

Tags: spring, autowired, factory-pattern

I have a spring application in which I am trying to inject many beans of the same type. I do not know how many of these beans there will be before runtime, so it seems natural to use the factory pattern, as I cannot configure each bean in my java config class. However, these beans need to have some of their fields wired by Spring, and when I create them with "new" in my factory, they are of course not Spring managed.

Is there a way to have the beans I create in my factory class be managed by Spring? Or is the factory pattern the wrong way to go about this?

I am fairly new to posting, so please let me know if any more information is necessary.

Comment: Please explain your use case in more detail. A prototype bean might be what you need, or perhaps you should reactor your bean to avoid field injection (always worth considering) and then use a factory that knows its dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a beanFactory wired with the dependencies needed for your bean, then manually injected them in each new bean created by the beanFactory. For example:

```
public class MyBean { 

   private Dependency1 dep1;
   private Dependency2 dep2;

   public MyBean(Dependency1 dep1, Dependency2 dep2) { 
      this.dep1 = dep1;
      this.dep2 = dep2;
   }
} 

@Component
public class MyBeanFactory {

    @Autowired 
    private Dependency1 dep1;

    @Autowired 
    private Dependency2 dep2;


    public MyBean createInstance() {
       return new MyBean(dep1, dep2);
    }      
}


@Component
public class MyBeanConsumer {
      @Autowired
      private MyBeanFactory myBeanFactory;


       public void foo() {                  
           final MyBean bean = myBeanFactory.createInstance();
       }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `@Autowired` because of the variable number of beans, but you can still make use of ApplicationContextAware to create obtain the beans.

Using that you can programmatically create prototype beans from your Java code if the type of bean has been defined before in the configuration, or alternatively you can create the new object in your factory using new, and then set the dependencies by using this same method.

This is an example of an implementation:

```
public final class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = context;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return CONTEXT != null ? CONTEXT.getBean(beanName) : null;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> objectClass) {
        return CONTEXT != null ? CONTEXT.getBean(objectClass) : null;
    }
}
```